# RuntimeException when converting graphics to RGB_565

Tags: android, bitmap, runtimeexception

I have an occasional crash report from Google Play Console for my game which I am finding difficult to fix. It's relatively rare, but it's the cause of a few 1-star reviews so far.

Thousands of times this code works fine, it's only rarely that it causes a fatal error (it's on start-up so it crashes out immediately for the user). It doesn't give me the reason why throwIfCannotDraw trips out.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: I think it could be a timing problem as it's at start-up and there's loads going on in other threads - loading/initialising ad networks, analytics, Google Play Services, etc. Anyone have experience with this?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1301)
      at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1356)
```

Here's the top few Devices causing the crash:

```
Galaxy Tab Pro 12.2 (v2wifi)        6   14.0%
Galaxy Tab Pro 10.1 (picassowifi)   5   11.6%
Galaxy Tap Pro 8.4 (mondrianwifi)   4   9.3%
Galaxy Note 10.1 (lt033g)       3   7.0%
Galaxy TabS 8.4 (klimtwifi)     3   7.0%
Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2lte)       3   7.0%
Zmax Pro (urd)              2   4.7%
Galaxy Note5 (noblelte)         2   4.7%
```

The Android version doesn't seem to be a cause:

```
Android 5.1 14  32.6%
Android 7.0 12  27.9%
Android 4.4 7   16.3%
Android 6.0 6   14.0%
```

The code:

```
bitmapTMP1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.map_charset);

bitmapTMP2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapTMP1,
        (int) (MAP_CHARSET_SX * scaleFactor),
        (int) (MAP_CHARSET_SY * scaleFactor),
        false);

bitmapTMP1.recycle();

bitmapMapCharset = Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmapTMP2.getWidth(), bitmapTMP2.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );

Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(bitmapMapCharset);

c.drawBitmap(bitmapTMP2,0,0,null); //HERE - Causes RuntimeException sometimes 

bitmapTMP2.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The problem was when scaleFactor = 1 (which occurs on very large tablets). I.e. no scaling, and the documentation says:

> If the specified width and height are the same as the current width
>   and height of the source bitmap, the source bitmap is returned and no
>   new bitmap is created.

So when I recycled what I thought was the source bitmap (
bitmapTMP1.recycle();), I was actually recycling the bitmap I went on to use.

Not sure why the Logcat RuntimeException didn't include "trying to use a recycled bitmap". That would of been helpful...